# Overwrite DrawImage in picturebox (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, drawimage

I've a program that draw an image in a **picturebox** with *DrawImage*. This image, a ball (.png transparent), every second is overwritten by another ball of different color. After 3-5 second the edge of the ball becomes bad, because of **overwriting**.

I tried to clean the background with a *FillRectangle* before any overwrite, but i need to preserve the windows form background. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

To anybody who will encounter this in the future:

```
g.Clear(Color.FromArgb(0,0,0,0)); //Clear the graphics with transparent as background
g.DrawImage(...); //Draw your image
```